# JavaScript IE issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following site:
http://webofdreams.ro/vworker/finemaid/finemaid.html

There are some java script(jquery 172) issues with it:
When loaded in IE9 it will go to the server folder instead of loading the index page.
in ie7+ when clicked the services tab and then again the overview tab it will do the same thing. 
It also seems to throw random errors every now and then.
Is there any incompatibility between jquery and IE7,8,9?
The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/custom3.js"></script>
</head>
       <div class="main">
            <div class="contentNav clearfix">
                <ul class="secondaryNav">
                    <li><a id="activeLink" class="show1 navButton left" href="">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a class="show2 navButton">Services</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="primaryContent clearfix">                   
                <div class="container clearfix">
                    <div  class="container1"> 
                        <h1>      
                            Fine Maid<br />                    
                             Bay C1 - 3911 Brandon St. S.E.<br />
                            Calgary, AB., T2G 4A7<br />                                                
                            (403) 454-5526<br />
                            For more information visit us at <a href=" http://www.finemaid.com/contact.php" title="Finemaid homepage" class="mainLink">www.finemaid.com</a>           
                        </h1>                    
                        <p class="clearfix">Fine Maid offers a fresh approach to the concept of Residential and Office Cleaning. Very openly, the company offers a variety of cleaning packages with fixed prices (which is something that many other major companies shy away from advertising on their websites). For custom cleaning projects or long-term janitorial cleaning contracts, Fine Maid will provide custom quotes upon consolations with prospective clients and visits to sites.</p>
                        <p>Many household are paying increased attention these days to their cleaning products used. Fine Maid offers residential cleaning services using – at customer's discretion – their eco friendly, scent-free, hypo-allergenic, and environmentally responsible cleaning products.
Fine Maid website provides a wealth of information regarding Government issued recall alerts, other advisory and useful content. For more information<a href="http://www.finemaid.com/useful_resources.php" target="_blank" title="More Info" class="mainLink"> visit here.</a></p>
                        <p>Booking your next cleaning appointment with Fine Maid can not be easier: for any of the fixed-priced residential / office cleaning packages, the website provides a step-by-step booking process (similar to an airline travel booking), allowing customers to book their preferred date and time for when the cleaning person or crew should arrive to their address to perform the cleaning tasks clearly stated in each package's description (which we recommend customers to read, for better understanding of what's included in a package and what not).</p>
                        <p>Fine Maid has clear-stated policies, and the "what happens if" is explained in great detail, giving customers peace of mind. You can book your next cleaning appointment in confidence with Fine Maid in Calgary and area!</p>         
                    </div>
                    <div class="container2">
                        <ul class="services">
                            <li>cleaning services Calgary </li>
                            <li>residential cleaning Calgary </li>
                            <li>office cleaning Calgary  </li>
                            <li>Calgary cleaning companies </li>
                            <li>cleaning Calgary</li>
                            <li>commercial cleaning Calgary</li>
                            <li>home cleaning Calgary</li>
                            <li>cleaning Calgary services</li>
                            <li>residential cleaning</li>
                            <li>Calgary cleaning services</li>
                            <li>Maid service Calgary</li>
                            <li>Calgary cleaning company</li>
                            <li>quality cleaning services </li>
                            <li>professional cleaning services Calgary</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="services">
                            <li>eco cleaning services</li>
                            <li>house cleaning Calgary</li>
                            <li>eco cleaning services Calgary</li>
                            <li>condo cleaning Calgary</li>
                            <li>scent-free cleaning products Calgary</li>
                            <li>hypo-allergenic cleaning products Calgary</li>
                            <li>environmentally responsible cleaning products Calgary</li>
                            <li>Calgary cleaning</li>
                            <li>Janitorial services Calgary</li>
                            <li>Carpet cleaning Calgary</li>
                            <li>quality cleaning services Calgary</li>
                            <li>Maid Calgary</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**custom3.js**

```
//show hide the main div 1 and 2 content
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show1').click(function(){
        if ($('.container1').is(':visible')){
            return
        }
        else { $('.container1').show()
            $('.container2').hide(); 
            $('.show1').attr('id', 'activeLink');
            $('.show2').removeAttr('id', 'activeLink');
        }
    });

    $('.show2').click(function(){
        if ($('container2').is(':visible')){
            return
        }
        else { $('.container2').show();
            $('.container1').hide();
            $('.show2').attr('id', 'activeLink');
            $('.show1').removeAttr('id', 'activeLink');
        }
    });            
});
```

​
​

Comment: Please post the specific code that you are having issues with and focus on one issue per question. This will allow your question to be more easily answered and make it possibly useful to others in the future.

Comment: I have added the specific piece of code that does not renders well. I use jquery 172 as you can see in the header.

Comment: You javascript is not in a script tag and your content is outside the body tag as well.

Comment: Instead of removing the id attribute of active link. I would recommend using a class and adding and remove the class of activeLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had any compatibility issues with jquery between different versions of IE. The jQuery crew has done an excellent job with making jquery compatible with all browsers. The issue is most likely in your javascript itself. IE is notorious for its issues with handling javascript.

Please be more specific with code examples and what issues you are experiencing.

**Edit**: Your html is outside of the body tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/custom3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     Content should go here
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**:

In the href for your links you should put `javascript:void(0)`. This will prevent the links from trying to go to the server. Also if you switch both of your links to have the same class `show` and switch your content divs to have the classes of `Overview` and `Services`, you should be able to simplify your javascript to something like this:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    if($(this).html() == "Overview") {
        $('.Sevices').hide();
        $('.Overview').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.Overview').hide();
        $('.Sevices').show();
    }

    $('.show').removeClass("activeLink");
    $(this).addClass("activeLink";
});
```

Comment: that is because is in an external page custom3.js

Comment: Ok but still your html is outsie the body tag.

Comment: I have solved it in the meantime, the problem is in the href="" in the overview link. If I take it out it works like a charm. This is very strange. Thanks for assistance thought. Also in the original code the html is within the body tag, you can check on the link I have posted.

Comment: My updated answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty string for an `href` on the overview link. So, it's attempting to "follow" to that `href`, which obviously doesn't exist.